# Task.WaitAny is hanging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

For some reason my Task.WaitAny line is hanging and I have no idea why.  I am trying to create new user in the problem line of code.  Here is the code:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EditUser([Bind(Include = "UserID, Email, UserName, Roles, RoleID, RoleName")] ManagerUserViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
                var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
                ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
                user.Email = model.Email;
                user.UserName = model.UserName;

                if (model.UserID == null || model.UserID == "" || model.UserID == "0")
                {
                    // Since it didn't have a UserID, we assume this is a new User

                    Task.WaitAny(manager.CreateAsync(user, "Changeitasap!2"));
```

Comment: You are waiting for the completion of a task that you never start. Is there any reason why you are not calling that async method asynchronously?

Comment: I'm pretty new at this, so I'm completely open to better methods.

Comment: What version of MVC are you using? You should be using [async/await for this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4).

Comment: @mike z, you are correct, that did it.  You can add an answer and I'll accept if you want.